# Python request post with multipart form data without uploading file

Tags: python, http-post, multipartform-data

I want to post data without uploading file, I've tried every possible way but unable to do so.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

MJl9tuO3473PMg1NfG2ih6wAIbBJ2Tehamd0WXmZlyqPtOcKaT6XQr9e3PGLtPQo
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

adg_lt10
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

adg_lt10@yopmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="city"

Yanbu
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="saudi_national"

true
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"

m
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phone_number"

+923134147647
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_day"

14
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_month"

6
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_year"

1992
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="organization"


------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="linkedin_url"


------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resume"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="delete-file"

No
------WebKitFormBoundary1Pofu6UFaasCiaLP--
```

Can someone please help here? I tried several things, like the following code for example, but I keep getting bad request errors from the server.

Any working example

Here is code:

```
    def fill_contact_form(self, email, username):
        url = self.hostname + '/application/contact'
        response = self.session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        middlewaretoken = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'})['value']
        token = response.cookies['csrftoken']
files = {"file": ('resume', open('test.jpg', "rb"), 'application/octet-stream')}
        fields = {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": middlewaretoken,
            "name": username,
            "email": email,
            "city": "Medina",
            "saudi_national": "true",
            "gender": "m",
            "phone_number": "+123435678910",
            "birth_day": "15",
            "birth_month": "6",
            "birth_year": "1990",
            "organization": "",
            "linkedin_url": "",
            "delete-file": "No"
        }
resp = self.session.post(url, data=fields, files=files)
```

What am I doing wrong here, any idea?

Comment: Could you share snippets of the code ? I am not sure what is this output of

Comment: @vegabondx just updated

Comment: I see could you elaborate also what do you mean by "without uploading the file" ?  why do you want to do that ? What doesnt work when you upload a file ? Which file you are talking about ( i guess its test.jpg ) am i correct ?

Comment: @vegabondx I don't want to upload any file. You can say that I want to send file parameter empty and other data as set in fields dict.

Comment: Hmm if you just remove the files from the post what error does it throw ( I check aiohttp referece and i dont think files is needed parameter ) i.e. if you dont send file it would be satisfied with data. I am not sure if your server with throw any exception if it is configured to see the file.

Comment: @vegabondx any example?